# Generate a random color of a random square in Javascript

Tags: javascript

The button is supposed to change the color of a random square to random color. 
This is my code, I figured out how to change the random color of every square at the same time, but it should pick only one random square at a time. Could you please have a look? The comments will show you my way of thinking:

```js
// Elements grabbed from the document
let square1 = document.getElementById('square1');
let square2 = document.getElementById('square2');
let square3 = document.getElementById('square3')
let button = document.getElementById('button');

//This picks a random number
const rgb = (num) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
};

const changeColorOfaRandomSquareToRandom = () => {
  //This I hope will pick a random square
  let array = [square1, square2, square3];
  let randomNumber = Math.floor[Math.random() * 3];

  // I assign the value of the randomSquare function to a new variable
  let squareRND = array[randomNumber];

  //This picks a random color
  let randomColor = 'rgb(' + rgb(255) + ',' + rgb(255) + ',' + rgb(255) + ')';
  return squareRND.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();


}

button.onclick = changeColorOfaRandomSquareToRandom();
```

```css
#square1{
  background-color: lightpink;
  width:200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 200px;
}


#square2{
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 200px;

}

#square3{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

#squares{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

#button{
  width: 75px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 600px;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="squares.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="squares">
  <div id="square1" onclick="colorChange">
  </div>
  <div id="square2">
  </div>
  <div id="square3">
  </div>
</div>
  <button id="button">Click me</button>
    <script src="square.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are creating functions inside your ``onclick`` function but not calling them, why don't you just execute that code instead of  wrapping them inside another functions?

Comment: Could you show me how to do that? :P Sorry to bother you, but I am a newby :D

Comment: I made a snippet of what you had with a simple button.  Please add the actual markup so that we may better assist with your issue here.  I also suggest you change the id from "button" to a more descriptive id perhaps?

Comment: You want me to add the css and html ?

Comment: Yes please, right now your question is OK make your question Great! https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  NOTE: make the questions easy to answer for people helping you.  I created the snippet to assist you in learning how to do that (create great questions)

Comment: Oh, Okay. No problem :) Just a sec.

Comment: Oh boy, I think I somehow removed your button :O

Comment: When you edit, click the snippet button OR hit CTRL-M  :) not being critical just trying to assist you in great question creation here :) I could fix it but better to teach you so you can enjoy the site better perhaps.

Comment: All right! :) Thx a lot for this useful lesson :D!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `Math.floor` should be within parenthesis instead of square brackets like:

`let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);`

Then you should get the element by id from the `squareRND` like:

`document.getElementById(squareRND).style.backgroundColor = randomColor`

You should also run the `colorChange();`

For example:

```js
let button = document.getElementById('button');
const changeColorOfaRandomSquareToRandom = () => {
  //This I hope will pick a random square
  let randomSquare = () => {
    let array = ['square1', 'square2', 'square3'];
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    return array[randomNumber]
  };

  // I assign the value of the randomSquare function to a new variable
  let squareRND = randomSquare();
  console.log(randomSquare());
  //This picks a random number
  let rgb = (num) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
  };

  //This picks a random color
  let colorChange = () => {
    let randomColor = 'rgb(' + rgb(255) + ',' + rgb(255) + ',' + rgb(255) + ')';
    document.getElementById(squareRND).style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
  };
  colorChange();
};

button.onclick = changeColorOfaRandomSquareToRandom;
```

```css
#square1 {
  background-color: lightpink;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

#square2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

#square3 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

#squares {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

#button {
  width: 75px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="squares">
  <div id="square1">
  </div>
  <div id="square2">
  </div>
  <div id="square3">
  </div>
</div>
<button id="button">Click me</button>
```

Comment: actually it changes color of a random square after refreshing the website each time... But thanx a lot, it was a clue for me :)

Comment: @darius.maximus Out of curiosity, why did you remove the checkmark?
 It changes color when the click event fires and the handler executes which it does on the button click. Feel free to consider upvoting all the answers that have proven helpful to you.

Comment: sorry, that was an experiment. I click this and that, trying to make myself feel at home on stack overflow :D  Yeah, I cannot upvote the answers couse it says I have less than 15 reputation points. To make the situation worse, my reputation is even worse after posting the question.

Answer (score 3):

in your `let array = ['square1', 'square2', 'square3'];`, if you pass in the variables directly rather than strings, it should work. Right now you are doing `'square1'.style.backgroundColor =`

Answer (score 0):

At the randomSquare method you have to return `document.getElementById(array[randomNumber])`

e.g

```
let randomSquare = () => {
 ...
  return document.getElementById(array[randomNumber]);
};
```

Comment: ofc you have to call the changeColor  at the end of the changeColorOfaRandomSquareToRandom()

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code, i have not tested yet:

```
// Elements grabbed from the document
let square1 = document.getElementById('square1');
let square2 = document.getElementById('square2');
let square3 = document.getElementById('square3')
let button = document.getElementById('button');

//This picks a random number
const rgb = (num) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
};

const changeColorOfaRandomSquareToRandom = () => {
  //This I hope will pick a random square
  let array = [square1, square2, square3];
  let randomNumber = Math.floor[Math.random() * 3];

  // I assign the value of the randomSquare function to a new variable
  let squareRND = array[randomNumber];

  //This picks a random color
  let randomColor = 'rgb(' + rgb(255) + ',' + rgb(255) + ',' + rgb(255) + ')';
  squareRND.style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
}

button.onclick = changeColorOfaRandomSquareToRandom;
```

You don't call your last function `colorChange()` anywhere, i don't get why you are creating functions inside your click event function.

Comment: I don't know why, I am totally new to this stuff, just trying this and that :P

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I tested it but still doesn;t work... :(

Comment: @darius.maximus what's the problem? Any errors in console?

Comment: yeay, it throws this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.changeColorOfaRandomSquareToRandom (square.js:23)
changeColorOfaRandomSquareToRandom @ square.js:23

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve it and finally (and accidentally) I've made it! :D
Let me show you:

```js
// Elements grabbed from the document
let square1 = document.getElementById('square1');
let square2 = document.getElementById('square2');
let square3 = document.getElementById('square3')
let button = document.getElementById('button');

let squares = ['square1', 'square2', 'square3'];

//This picks a random square from the array and changes color
const randomize = () => {
  let randomSquare = squares[Math.floor(Math.random() * squares.length)];
  let randomColor = 'rgb(' + rgb(255) + ',' + rgb(255) + ',' + rgb(255) + ')';
  document.getElementById(randomSquare).style.background = randomColor;
}

//Draws a number for a random color
let rgb = (num) => {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * num)
};

  //Function attached to a button
button.onclick = randomize;
```

```css
#square1{
  background-color: lightpink;
  width:200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
}


#square2{
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;

}

#square3{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

#squares{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

#button{
  width: 75px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 600px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="squares.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="square.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="squares">
  <div id="square1" onclick="colorChange">
  </div>
  <div id="square2">
  </div>
  <div id="square3">
  </div>
</div>
  <button id="button">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```